# Convert nested c#-type to json and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json, reflection, deep-copy

I have a `C#` class as container for constant values used by the application.

```
public abstract class MyConstants
{
    public abstract class HttpMethods
    {
        public const string Put = "PUT";
        public const string Post = "POST";
        public const string Get = "GET";
    }

    public abstract class ContainerKeys
    {
        public abstract class GlobalModal
        {
            public const string DialogId = "6698CB2F-2948-45D9-8902-2C13A7ED6335";
        }
    }

    public const int MaximumImageUploadSize = 3 * 1024 * 1024; // 3MB
    public const int MaximumDocumentUploadSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
}
```

How can this be converted to a json which can then be copied inside to a `javascript`-file to use it like `MyConstants.HttpMethods.Put` inside `javascript`?

Using

```
var constants = typeof(MyConstants).GetFields().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(null));
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(constants);
return JavaScript(json + ";");
```

only returns `{"MaximumImageUploadSize":3145728,"MaximumDocumentUploadSize":5242880};` without all the nested classes/constants.

The question seems more related to use reflection on a `Type` with muliple nested other `Type`s.

Comment: Did you try to use Newtonsoft.Json, maybe that one will do it the way you need? (It has lots of configuration)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have instances of your classes in your `MyConstants` class. That's why it is not visible.

Simplified example below:

```
public abstract class MyConstants
{
    public class HttpMethods
    {
        public const string Put = "PUT";
        public const string Post = "POST";
        public const string Get = "GET";
    }

    public const int MaximumImageUploadSize = 3 * 1024 * 1024; // 3MB
    public const int MaximumDocumentUploadSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // 5MB
    public const HttpMethods HttpMethodObj;
}
```

Comment: This throws an `Member with the same name is already declared`. Also the `class` should still be `abstract`.

Comment: Yeah, just rename new property

Comment: The "real" class (currently) contains of more than 1500 lines. So, adding a new property for each class/property seems not like the best solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need abit of recursion to build the dictionary:

## Example

```
Dictionary<string, object> TypeToDictionary(Type type)
{
    var ret = type.GetFields().ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x.GetValue(null));

    foreach (var nestedType in type.GetNestedTypes())
    {
        ret.Add(nestedType.Name, TypeToDictionary(nestedType));
    }
    
    return ret;
}
```

## Usage

```
var dictionary = TypeToDictionary(typeof(MyConstants));
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

## Output

```
{
  "MaximumImageUploadSize": 3145728,
  "MaximumDocumentUploadSize": 5242880,
  "HttpMethods": {
    "Put": "PUT",
    "Post": "POST",
    "Get": "GET"
  },
  "ContainerKeys": {
    "GlobalModal": {
      "DialogId": "6698CB2F-2948-45D9-8902-2C13A7ED6335"
    }
  }
}
```

### Note

I used `Newtonsoft.JSON` but `JavaScriptSerializer` should work also.